# Return object instead of string for FK field in SerializerMutation in Graphene Django

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have two models `ProjectType` and `Project` as follows

```
class ProjectType(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'project_types'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Project(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    project_type = models.ForeignKey(ProjectType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='related_projects')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'projects'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

and I have Mutations for both using `SerializerMutation` from Grapehene Django

```
class ProjectTypeMutation(SerializerMutation):
    class Meta:
        serializer_class = ProjectTypeSerializer
        model_operation = ['create', 'update']


class ProjectMutation(SerializerMutation):
    class Meta:
        serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
        model_operation = ['create', 'update']


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    cudProjectType = ProjectTypeMutation.Field()
    cudProject = ProjectMutation.Field()
```

When I perform a create mutation for project, I have to also specify the `project_type`. The resulting response also has the `project_type` but as a String. Not an object. Is there any way to get `project_type` back as an object?

**Current Mutation** ⬇️

```
mutation{
  cudProject(input: {name: "Project1" project_type: "1"}) {
    id
    name
    project_type
  }
}
```

**Current Output** ⬇️

```
{
  "data": {
    "cudProject": {
      "id": 200,
      "name": "Project1",
      "project_type": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

I want project_type to be an object which I can use as follows:

**Expected Mutation Request** ⬇️ (This brings an error currently)

```
mutation{
  cudProject(input: {name: "Project1" project_type: "1"}) {
    id
    name
    project_type{
      id
      name
  }
}
```

**Expected Output** ⬇️

```
{
  "data": {
    "cudProject": {
      "id": 200,
      "name": "Project1",
      "project_type": {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "ProjectType1"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do this using `SerializerMutation` or any other way in Graphene Django?

Or if there is a better way to have Create, Update, Delete Mutations implemented in Graphene Django, that could also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by adding a custom resolver to nested models.
BTW, you also need to define a grahpql type for `ProjectType` if you didn't do so already.

Here is a simple example:

```py
class ProjectTypeType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
      model = ProjectType
      fields = ('id', 'name')


class ProjectMutation(SerializerMutation):
    class Meta:
        serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
        model_operation = ['create', 'update']

    project_type = graphne.Field(ProjectTypeType)

    @classmethod
    def resolve_project_type(cls, root, info)
      return ProjectType.objects.get(pk=root.project_type.pk)  # <- NOTE: project_type is PKOnlyObject here
```

Of course you might want to leverage DataLoaders in order to solve N+1 problem.
Pl